# Add another role to a user when they click a button?

Tags: php, functions, users, user-roles, user-meta

On my site, there are roles "user, authors, etc.".
Default role for user is "User" which I want to keep it for all users.

**How to add another role to a user when they click a button?**

I tried with my code below but it doesn't work.

I have a page "Create a Post" that I want to restrict it to authors only.
So, when a normal logged-in user tries to access the "Create a Post" page,
they will be present with a form to apply as Author which they only need to click the button.

After they click "Apply" button, they will immediately get the Author role and immediately have access to the frontend post editor in the "Create a Post" page.

Here's my code:

```
/// APPLY AS AUTHOR BUTTTON
add_shortcode( 'apply_as_author', 'apply_as_author_button_shortcode' );

function apply_as_author_button_shortcode() {
if(is_user_logged_in()) {
$user = wp_get_current_user();
?>
<form method="POST">
<div style="text-align:center;">
<div>
    <p>
    <h3 style="margin:auto;">Apply to be an author?</h3>
    <input checked="checked" type="hidden" class="input-checkbox" name="author_checkbox" id="author_checkbox" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->author_checkbox ); ?>" />
    <br />
    <span style="font-size:16px;margin:auto;">
    Your application to be an author will be approved immediately right after you click the apply button.<br />
    As an author, share your best stories and new ideas, and get discovered by many!
    </span>
</p>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" class="apply-author-button" name="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply', 'wordpress' ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" />
</p>
</div>
</div>
</form>
<?php
}}

// ADD AUTHOR ROLE
add_action('profile_update', 'role_option_update_user_meta');
function role_option_update_user_meta( $user_id ) {
if ( isset($_POST['author_checkbox']) ) {
    $user_id = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'role' => $_POST['role'] ) );
    if( $user_id > 0 ){
        $user = new WP_User($user_id);
        $user->add_role('author');
    }
}
}
```

Comment: the action [profile_update]() is only fired when a user is updated in the dashboard.  You need to hook your function on [init](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) instead.

Comment: @Aurovrata I've just tried `init` but doesn't work. I don't see "author" role in the user account after a user clicked the apply button.

Comment: well likely you have an error in your code.  Are you getting a value in your submitted post `$_POST['author_checkbox']`